# Scrapy Contracts - Unhandled error in Deferred

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am writing a spider using Scrapy, and I am currently adding contracts to the spider. The spider is still running fine, but I am getting weird results when running checks, after adding *@returns* in the contracts.

```
@returns response 1
```

I am suddenly getting *"Unhandled error is Deferred"* when running *scrapy check*:

```
$ scrapy check regjeringen_no

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 contracts in 0.000s

OK
Unhandled error in Deferred:
```

The spider code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*
import scrapy

class RegjeringenNoSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    '''A spider to crawl the Norwegian Government's pages containing news, speeches and opinions'''
    name = "regjeringen_no"
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.regjeringen.no/no/aktuelt/taler_artikler/',
        'https://www.regjeringen.no/no/aktuelt/nyheter/',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        '''Parses the response downloaded for each of the requests made. Some
        contracts are mingled with this docstring.

        @url https://www.regjeringen.no/no/aktuelt/taler_artikler/ 
        @url https://www.regjeringen.no/no/aktuelt/nyheter/
        @returns response 1
        '''

        self.logger.info('Parse function called on %s', response.url)

        for href in response.css('li.listItem h2.title a::attr(href)'):
            yield response.follow(href, callback=self.parse_article)

        for href in response.css('li.next a::attr(href)'):
            yield response.follow(href, callback=self.parse)

    def parse_article(self, response):
        '''Parse response for pages with a single article'''
        self.logger.info('Parse article function called on %s', response.url)

        yield {
            'article_title': self._extract_with_css("header.article-header h1::text", response),
            'article_date': self._extract_with_css("div.article-info span.date::text", response),
            'article_type': self._extract_with_css("div.article-info span.type::text", response),
            'article_lead': self._extract_with_css("div.article-ingress p::text", response),
            'article_text': self._extract_with_css("div.article-body::text", response),
        }

    def _extract_with_css(self, query, response):
        return response.css(query).extract_first().strip()
```

Two things are odd here. First, that the feedback from *scrapy check* says 0 contracts, even though there are 3 (In fact, contracts seem to be counted only when they fail). Second, the error message, which does not make much sense (btw, the error does not interrupt the execution of the check). Scrapy bugs?

Note: Running

```
$ scrapy shell "https://www.regjeringen.no/no/aktuelt/taler_artikler/"
```

gives me:

```
[s] Available Scrapy objects:
[s]   scrapy     scrapy module (contains scrapy.Request, scrapy.Selector, etc)
[s]   crawler    <scrapy.crawler.Crawler object at 0x7fbf214b6dd0>
[s]   item       {}
[s]   request    <GET https://www.regjeringen.no/no/aktuelt/taler_artikler/>
[s]   response   <200 https://www.regjeringen.no/no/aktuelt/taler_artikler/id1334/>
[s]   settings   <scrapy.settings.Settings object at 0x7fbf214b6d50>
[s]   spider     <DefaultSpider 'default' at 0x7fbf20e1e1d0>
[s] Useful shortcuts:
[s]   fetch(url[, redirect=True]) Fetch URL and update local objects (by default, redirects are followed)
[s]   fetch(req)                  Fetch a scrapy.Request and update local objects 
[s]   shelp()           Shell help (print this help)
[s]   view(response)    View response in a browser
>>>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect poor exception reporting here is a scrapy bug. Contracts are still considered a new feature and are also [pretty limited](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/1918). As for what is going on: you are supposed to specify `@returns requests 1` not `@returns responses 1`. Specifying multiple `@url` directives will also not work for you and only the first url will be checked, I am not sure how to address that frankly without actually extending contracts functionality.

Comment: Thx, @john-smith. Fixed the contract and are now getting "Ran 1 contract in 0.893s" from scrapy check regjeringen_no. That's odd, since there are 2 contracts, but anyway... With regards to the two urls; will try to get it working with two using custom contracts.

Comment: I believe the runner doesn't count `@url` directives here since they don't perform any checks of their own (or because they also get special treatment by the runner, like being implicitly mandatory)

Comment: Ok. Btw: Have had a careful look at the docs, and they are quite limited. That, and the limited error reporting, doesn't make contracts as easy to use as they initially seemed to be... There is a few bug reports to this effect on Scrapy's GitHub, among other https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/1918.